# Распарсить несколько ответов

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Get-запросом получаю нное кол-во сообщений. В каждом сообщении есть  ключ content_id_out и его значение. Кодом ниже достаю. Но достаю из одного. Вопрос: Как достать значения этого ключа из ВСЕХ сообщений и сложить в словарь?

```
dii = json.loads(news)
act = dii['items'][0]['content_id_out']
```

Comment: 1) Доставать циклом 2) Не описано в вопросе какая будет структура у словаря

Comment: https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ Вот эту библиотеку глянте

Comment: @gil9red просто числа

Comment: @СергейБогданов, нужно описывать подробнее или не писать про словарь :) Допустим, под числами вы имеете ввиду значения `content_id_out`, но тогда непонятно что в значения писать, `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
dii = json.loads(news)

d = dict()

for x in dii['items']:
    act = x['content_id_out']
    d[act] = None
```

**UPD.**

```
dii = json.loads(news)
ids = [x['content_id_out'] for x in dii['items']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоватся генератором словарей, только следует учитывать, что если у вас 'content_id_out' в исходном списке может принимать не уникальные значения, то в этом случае число ключей в словаре на выходе будет меньше, чем длина исходного списка

```py
dii = json.loads(news)
dict_out = {"%s" %i['content_id_out']: None for i in dii['items']}
```

Можно воспользоваться генератором списков, тогда ВСЕ значения из исходного списка туда попадут:

```py
list_out = ["%s" %i['content_id_out'] for i in dii['items']]
```

Answer (score 0):

@gil9red Я вот так решил

```
dii = json.loads(news)
ids = []
for msg in range( len(dii['items'])):
    ids.append( dii['items'][msg]['content_id_out'])
```

Comment: К сожалению, не было уведомления, т.к. это работает только в комментариях :( Я актуализирую свой ответ